# check constraint check the column twice

Tags: oracle, constraints

What is wrong in this error ?

> alter table INFO add constraint chk_app check
>   (CASE WHEN app IS  NULL THEN app = 'A');

If its because  *app = 'A'* I am calling it twice then how to have a check constraint to check if app is null then it should have value A

Comment: A check constraint _checks_ something, you need a comparison operator (also a CASE statement needs an END). If you just want to ensure that if app is null then it should be A then you should use wolφi's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the column app to 'A' whenever a row is inserted with a NULL value, I'd use a DEFAULT construct:

```
 ALTER TABLE info MODIFY (app VARCHAR2(xxx) DEFAULT 'A');
```

If no value is specified during an `INSERT`, an 'A' is inserted into column `app`. Of course, a user can override this behaviour by explicitly inserting a NULL value. This can be prevented by a `NOT NULL` constraint:

```
 ALTER TABLE info MODIFY (app VARCHAR2(xxx) DEFAULT 'A' NOT NULL);
```

From Oracle version 12c on, you can specify the required behaviour more clearly:

```
 ALTER TABLE info MODIFY (app VARCHAR2(xxx) DEFAULT ON NULL 'A' NOT NULL);
```

Comment: This is not the best answer, see Petr's answer, i made an example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/78aaa/1

Answer (score 3):

This is bacause check constraint only checks the value, it is not able to change it.

You can simply add default value to app column or write before insert or update trigger like this

```
create or replace trigger info_briu
before insert or update of info
for each row
begin
  if :new.app is null then
    :new.app := 'A';
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: A trigger is massive overkill for this situation.

Comment: Maybe, but if the insert supplies a null value for the column then a default value is not going to be applied. Of course the insert would not do that.

Comment: yes, I agree with Ben in most cases. but is does not help in cases when user directly stores null value, like INSERT INTO info(app) VALUES (NULL)

Comment: Petr is right - trigger is (imo) only working solution here, see an example, what is wrong with DEFAULT constraint solution: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/78aaa/1

Comment: @PetrPribyl: To be honest, I'd neither use a default nor a trigger in this case. If NULL always means 'A', why not stick with the NULL?

Comment: Don't you think that's a little over the top @Pavel, it's not the only solution and will mean some overhead where it's not necessary. There's no need to use a trigger, see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d01d4/1

Comment: You can always declare the column as not null @David, which would stop that from happening.

Comment: @Ben: Yes declaring NOT NULL is here the win - simple and good. It could be the content of your first comment - don't complain without alternatives :)